# Set Azure Storage Account mount path with Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

Previously, with Azure CLI script, I had the following Storage Account config:

```
az webapp config storage-account add \
  --resource-group $resourceGroup \
  --name $functionAppName \
  --storage-type AzureFiles \
  --share-name $shareName \
  --custom-id $shareId \
  --account-name $AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT \
  --mount-path $mountPath \
```

Now, I'm trying to write this with Bicep, but I can't find any config for `mount-path`. Is there any possibility to set this in a Bicep file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Web Apps - Update Azure Storage Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/update-azure-storage-accounts) accepts a dictionary of storage properties, so something like that should work:

```bicep
var webAppName = 'web app name'
var storageAccountName = 'storage account name'
var shareName = 'share name'
var mountPath = 'mount path'

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' existing = {
  name: storageAccountName
}

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-01-15' existing = {
  name: webAppName
}
resource storageSetting 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-01-15' = {
  name: 'azurestorageaccounts'
  parent: webApp
  properties: {
    '${shareName}': {
      type: 'AzureFiles'
      shareName: shareName
      mountPath: mountPath
      accountName: storageAccount.name
      accessKey: storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. But I still can't understand. Why I had to group all those props under `properties > shareName`?

Comment: You can pass a list of shares and it expexts unique names for each share. Yeah i know it s somehow weird...